# JAX-RS 2.1 ClientBuilder.newBuilder() readTimeout and connectTimeout not working

Tags: jax-rs

I tried setting the timeouts small to force the failures to see what happens:

```
ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
  .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
  .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
```

But the code still seems to hang for what feels like the default timeout values.

Answer (score 1):

[readTimeout](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/2.1/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html#readTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) and [connectTimeout](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/2.1/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html#connectTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) both accept a `TimeUnit` parameter so it makes sense the `NANOSECONDS` would be ok right?

The javadoc for these both read:

> Value 0 represents infinity. Negative values are not allowed.

And these are internally converted to `MILLISECONDS` via `TimeUnit.convert` which states:

> Conversions from finer to coarser granularities truncate, so lose precision.

That is what is happening here. `TimeUnit.convert` even has an example:

> For example, converting {@code 999} milliseconds to seconds results in {@code 0}.

Which would be a similar problem for converting 1 nanosecond to milliseconds resulting in 0.

And 0 is infinity... that is, the operating system default timeouts.

Clearly this is obvious, but none of the Javadocs indicate that the specified times will be internally converted into MILLISECONDS and to beware of losing precision.

And I've wasted days wondering why this wasn't working, when I should have remembered from years of network programming milliseconds are the default units.